# RT - ShowTicket allows me to reply?

Tags: permissions, rt

I have a permissions problem with "group rights" section.

I have two groups:
A, B.

A - full permissions

B - read-only ( ShowTicket )

The problem is - group B members can still reply to the ticket, and I don't understand why?

Since there's a permissions parameter extactly for that ( ReplyToTicket )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a global permission - ReplyToTicket granted to Everyone or similar.